# python telnetlib expect error: TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnetlib

I am trying to pass 2 precompiled regular expressions to python's telnetlib expect method, but I get: TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object. Sample code is below:

```
import re,sys,telnetlib

tn=telnetlib.Telnet('localhost',23,10)

re_list=[re.compile("login:",re.I),re.compile("username:",re.I)]
print("re_list:",re_list)
# Expect gets errors here
index,obj,data=tn.expect(re_list,10)
```

Sample output is below:

```
python tn_exp_bug.py
re_list: [<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x00A49E90>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x00A6CB60>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tn_exp_bug.py", line 8, in <module>
index,obj,data=tn.expect(re_list,10)
File "c:\python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 652, in expect
return self._expect_with_select(list, timeout)
File "c:\python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 735, in _expect_with_select
m = list[i].search(self.cookedq)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object</pre>
```

Other details:
I am running on Windows XP, Python version 3.3.0. I checked bugs.python.org and there is only 1 open bug for telnet, which doesnt seem at all relevant.

Comment: try `re.compile(b"login:",re.I)` instead.

Comment: Glad it helped, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You tried using string pattern on a bytes object, while you should use a byte pattern:

```
re.compile(b"login:",re.I),re.compile(b"username:",re.I)
```